# What's the Best Way to Get a "Pull to Refresh" from a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swipe

I have a [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/), and it displays data received from a WiFi-connected device.

I want to do the fairly bog-standard gesture response of dragging a table down, then releasing it, to trigger an update.

I guess I could attach a swipe gesture recognizer to the table's substrate view, but I'm wondering if there is a way to intercept this gesture directly from the table itself.

> **META:**
>
> I've been looking through the various docs and whatnot. I haven't had
>   to do this before, so I never gave it any thought. Now I see that I
>   probably should have thought about it.
>
> If this is an obvious solution, I don't mind being told so, as long as
>   you help me to find the "obvious" remedy. I'll delete this question if
>   it's a bad one.
>
> However, I haven't found a solution, and I'm usually fairly good at
>   that kind of thing.
>
> **UPDATE** I changed the title to better reflect what I'm asking.

Comment: Have you looked into the Pull To Refresh a table view?

Comment: Hmm... [this one?](http://www.appcoda.com/pull-to-refresh-uitableview-empty/) It may be how we ask the question... I'll dig deeper. Even if this is a dumb question, I may leave it up if it helps anyone. I don't have much shame.

Comment: Yes, something like that.  I have implemented that many times in my table views.

Comment: Why don't you implement the standard, built-in "pull-to-refresh" feature of `UITableView`? Why implement your own using a gesture?

Comment: I'm afraid @Tim has the right answer... there's a native way of doing it

Comment: Well, I won't be able to add a UITableViewController on top of the one I already have (there's a reason for that I won't go into). That does sound like the best way. However, I'll be using the @Ian method. It does mean that I need to cast the UITableView to UIScrollView when I assign the scroller delegate, but it works perfectly, and is very, very simple.

Comment: Don't be afraid to `addChildViewController` in order to get this native `UITableViewController` functionality. Rolling your own is always more error-prone. @Tim's answer is much better than mine if you specifically want a "pull to refresh" functionality. Your original question title indicated that you might just want a generic pull-down.

Comment: Oh, it's not that. I'm writing a tutorial, and this is the very simplest way to do it (least code). It's not against the rules, but I can't spend a bunch of time explaining it beyond simply doing this.

Comment: Don't use it at all. Pull-to-refresh and other revealing "hacks" are very bad UX. Not because people don't know how to pull but because they don't pull every day. And your searchbox can become forgotten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a `UIScrollViewDelegate` to your `UITableView`, you can respond to `scrollViewDidScroll:` events. A negative `contentOffset.y` value indicates that your user has pulled down at the top of your tableview.

Comment: Awesome! You get a green check in a few minutes! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The totally native way to do it is to use a UITableViewController in your UIViewController, e.g.

```
{
    tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
    [tableViewController setTableView:myTableView];

    refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [tableViewController setRefreshControl:refreshControl];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
```

Comment: @MAGSHARE, this is what I was talking about and what rmaddy mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing. Even though it is not the most "legal" way to do things, it is still highly effective, and absurdly simple:

I set up a scrollview delegate trap, like so, and added it to the delegate class:

```
//*******************************************
// Reacts to the table's scroller being changed.
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                     withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
              targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog ( @"MyViewController::scrollViewWillEndDragging:%@withVelocity:(%f,%f)targetContentOffset:(%f,%f)",scrollView,velocity.x, velocity.y, targetContentOffset->x, targetContentOffset->y );
#endif

    // We have to have had a "hard pull South" to trigger a refresh of the objects.
    if ( (velocity.y < 0) && ([scrollView contentOffset].y < -60) ) {
#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog ( @"We will perform a new refresh." );
#endif
    }
}
```

The "-60" is because I'm looking for the best offset before I set it into a static.