# Pull To Refresh issue with TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I have added pull to refresh in UITableview with two custom prototype cells ,I have tryied with these two type of code one through adding UIRefreshcontrol as a subview of tableview and other through UITableViewController

**1)UIRefreshcontrol as a subview of tableview**

```
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
self.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[listTable addSubview:self.refreshControl];
```

**2)Through UITableViewController**

```
UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
tableViewController.tableView = listTable;

self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshContacts) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
tableViewController.refreshControl = self.refreshControl;
```

But neither both of them seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Check these links for information

[UIRefreshControl - Pull To Refresh in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059510/uirefreshcontrol-pull-to-refresh-in-ios-7)

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/better-code-implement-pull-to-refresh-in-your-ios-apps/

Example

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
refreshControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[refreshControl addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(getLatestData)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[yourTableviewName addSubview:refreshControl];


   -(void)getLatestData
{
 // here add your reload method
  [self XXXXX]; 

  NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, h:mm a"];
   NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last update: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
   NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor]
                                                                    forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
   NSAttributedString *attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:attrsDictionary];
        refreshControl.attributedTitle = attributedTitle;

        [refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }
```

Comment: @selector itself is not getting called and I cant find the activity indicator when I drag down the tableview

Answer (score 0):

The second way is nearly identical to the code I suggested in [What's the Best Way to Get a "Pull to Refresh" from a UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28768534/) , so I'm thinking that your bug is in the tableViewController.  Is it getting retained?

Comment: Does tableview constraints issue affects the refreshcontrol ??

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the problem with your code is that your UITableViewController isn't being retained (that I can see); none of your other variables are referencing it.  If your UITableViewController is getting released by ARC, `tableViewController.refreshControl = self.refreshControl;` won't do anything.  My guess is that if you add tableViewController as a strong property to your object, this code should work.

Answer (score 0):

**In .h**

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) UIRefreshControl *refreshControl;
```

**In .m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 //Initialize the refresh control
    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshBrandList:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.tableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];

}


-(void) refreshBrandList:(id)sender{
    [self ServiceCall];
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];


}
```

Comment: I am already using this piece of code please suggest some other different answers

Comment: whats your trouble is it your selector isn't working or you don't see refresh icon

Comment: I dont see neither refresh icon and @selector working

Answer (score 0):

SVPullToRefresh + SVInfiniteScrolling

- Easy to use.
- Provide Pull up and down to refresh

[Easy to add pull-to-refresh and infinite scrolling fonctionalities to any UIScrollView or UITableView](https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Using this can we update the frame of the refresh icon bit lower ? ,I find the refresh icon on the extreme top So, that it is not fully visible

Comment: Yes, You can. You need to edit UIActivityIndicatorView style with a white large in SvPullToRefreshView Class and put appropriate tint color if needed.